# Docker volume created with nfs server is not reflecting the data from nfs server

Tags: docker, volume, nfs, docker-swarm

I have created an NFS server in an AWS Ubuntu instance. Below is the exposed nfs device from NFS server.

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvdb        30G  173M   28G   1% /mnt
```

Now in my swarm manager node, I am creating the nfs volume using this nfs server,

```
docker volume create --driver local --opt type=nfs --opt o=addr=<EC2 IP Address>,rw --opt device=:/dev/xvdb --name foo2
```

It will create the volume but inside the volume mountpoint, it is not displaying the data which is present in the NFS server's `/mnt` dir. I want to use the NFS server directly, I don't want to mount it to some local file.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems quite similar to below -
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/25202

You should use below while creating the service -

```
docker service create --mount type=volume,volume-opt=o=addr=192.168.99.1,volume-opt=device=:/Volumes/HDD/tmp,volume-opt=type=nfs ...
```